# Setting socketTimeout using httpclient in Java does not take effect

Tags: http

The httpclient version is as follows:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

The code is as follows：

```
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(100).setConnectTimeout(600).build();
        httpPost.setConfig(requestConfig);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, new ResponseHandler<String>() {
                @Override
                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (status == 200) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        return (entity == null) ? null : EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), Consts.UTF_8);
                    } else {
                        throw new ClientProtocolException("call HTTP Exception：" + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), Consts.UTF_8));
                    }
                }

            });
            return response;
        } finally {
            httpClient.close();
            httpPost.releaseConnection();
        }
```

Occasionally, in practice, the call time may exceed the sum of connectTimeout and socketTimeout, exceeding 800ms.What I expect is to exceed 600ms and throw a

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out